# What is allowing re-render when set state is setting the state to the same string?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have `setToken("unset")` in the useCallback of the first button click which causes re-render of the parent and the child; because it's button text changes. This is correct but, how is a second click causing  the parent to re-render?

Third click does nothing as I expected the second to do (token is set to a value of "unset" on each click).

I have to change `setToken('unset');` to `if(token!=='unset'){setToken('unset');}` and add `token` to the callback's dependencies to stop it re-rendering after the first re-render on first click. **I thought React re-renders when useState value is updated *and* different than the previous value.**

Why does React allow one extra re-render here? Why did React need me to do what I thought it was suppose to do?

Console:

| Without Condition | With |
| --- | --- |
| render parent, token: a7ib0PcX9 | render parent, token: a7ib0PcX9 |
| render Logout | render Logout |
| clicked | clicked |
| render parent, token: unset | render parent, token: unset |
| render Logout | render Logout |
| clicked | clicked |
| render parent, token: unset | clicked |
| clicked | clicked |
| clicked |  |
| clicked |  |

```
function Logout({ username, onLogout }) {
    console.log('render Logout');
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onLogout}>{username?('Logout '+username):'Buh Bye!'}</button>
        </>
    );
}
const MemoizedLogout = React.memo(Logout);

function AppLogout({ store }) {
    const [token, setToken] = useState('a7ib0PcX9');
    console.log('render parent,','token: '+token);
    const onLogout=useCallback(() => {
        console.log('clicked');
        store.username = undefined;
        setToken('unset');
    }, [store]);
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <header>
                <MemoizedLogout username={store.username} onLogout={onLogout}/>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
function App(){
    return (
        <>
            <AppLogout store={{username:'benz'}}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't, seems like a fail on the part of React. If a useSate is equal to the previous value and re-renders regardless then it doesn't do what it claims to do.

Comment: I changed the code to force correct behavior and the result was correct and react suffered none. React did not need to render that specific component again before bailing out because if it did then it would cause unexpected behavior with React or my code after my fix.